# Add billing address to user on registration

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, users, registration

I  am working on a craftcms + commerce project and I need to add a billing address to new user during its registration process. The idea is to have a billing address added to any newly registered user (no shipping address needed, as the shop will deliver no physical product).

I have been struggling with this and managed to get the user registered and the address record created in the DB with a 2-step form flow (first register user, then add address), but the address does not get linked to the user.

Is this possible or perhaps I am trying something completely against the way craftcms/commerce works?

Comment: That should definitely work... are you successfully populating the userId field in the save-user form when saving the address?

Comment: I think I figured out how this works. craftcms/commerce creates a "floating" customer as soon as a guest (not logged user) visits the page. In order to properly add addresses to a user (frontend) it has to be logged in.  
So the process would be: register user -> activate -> user logs in -> user adds addresses.  
I am thinking a way would be checking if the user has any registered address in the login form and:  
- If they  have no addresses, set a redirect to the profile/add address form.  
- If they already have at least one address, set a redirect to homepage.